# lower bound on norm of matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, normed-spaces

I'm wondering if the following inequality holds

$ \sigma_{min}\|v\|_2 \leq \|Av\|_2$

, where $ \sigma_{min}$ is the smallest singular value of A. Furthermore, assuming that A is positive definite and $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, this is quite easy to prove using the fact the orthogonal transformations preserve length.  Just write out $Av=U\Sigma V^{T}v$ and proceed in the obvious way.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I think I worked it out and will post my proof below. Maybe you could give it a quick look!

Comment: Does the opposite equality hold for the upper bound with the max singular value? i.e. $||Av||_2 \leq \sigma_{max}||v||_2$? I think so, but I want someone to confirm my derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian noted above we have from a SVD that: $Av=UΣV^Tv$, with $U$ and $V$ orthogonal and for orthogonal matrices holds $\|Av\|=\|v\|$.

Thus:
$$\|Av\|_2=\|UΣV^Tv\|_2=\|U(ΣV^T)v\|_2=\|V^T(Σv)\|_2=\|Σv\|_2=\sqrt{\sigma_1^2v_1^2+...+\sigma_n^2v_n^2}\\ \geq \sqrt{\sigma^2_{\min}(v_1^2+...+v_n^2)}=\sigma_{\min}\|v\|_2$$

Comment: There's a part of this I don't follow (I'm probably just missing something about orthogonal matrices).  I get how $||U\Sigma V^{\top} v||_{2} = ||\Sigma V^{\top} v||_{2}$ follows from orthogonality of $U$.  What I don't get is how $||U\Sigma V^{\top} v||_{2} = ||V^{\top} \Sigma v||_{2}$?  How did $V^{\top}$ and $\Sigma$ switch order?

Comment: @John Did you manage to find a correct proof?

Comment: @JoseBrox I think this is the relation

$$\|Av\|_2=\|UΣV^Tv\|_2=\|U(ΣV^T)v\|_2= ||\Sigma V^T v|| =\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1\sum_{i=1}^d v_{1i}b_i \\ \vdots \\ \sigma_d\sum_{i=1}^d v_{di}b_i \end{bmatrix}  \right\rVert  = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \sigma_k^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^d v_{ki}b_i\right)^2} \geq \sigma_{\min} \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \left(\sum_{i=1}^d v_{ki}b_i\right)^2} =  \sigma_{\min} ||V^Tv|| =  \sigma_{\min} ||v||$$

Answer (score 4):

Be careful: the current accepted best answer posted by Jonasson might be confusing if $A$ is not a square matrix. Even though the author mentioned $A$ was positive definite (hence necessarily square), using the singular value decomposition in its general form may suggest $A$ is rectangular. I personally think it would have been sufficient and clearer to use the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ in this specific case.

In particular, there is a dimension mismatch in $V^\top\Sigma v$ if $A$ is not a square matrix. However, the result is still valid when $A$ has a general rectangular form; following what Thoth wrote in a more concise way:

$\| Av \|_2^2 = \| U\Sigma V^\top v \|_2^2 = \| \Sigma V^\top v\|_2^2$ since $U$ is orthogonal. In addition, noting $\sigma_i$ the $i^{\text{th}}$ singular value of $A$ and using the fact that $\sigma_i \geq \sigma_{\text{min}} \geq 0$ for all $i$, one has

$$\| \Sigma V^\top v\|_2^2 = \| \Sigma (V^\top v)\|_2^2 = \sum_{i}\sigma_i^2 |(V^\top v)_i|^2 \geq \sigma_{\min}^2 \sum_{i} |(V^\top v)_i|^2 = \sigma_{\min}^2 \|V^\top v\|^2 = \sigma_{\min}^2 \|v\|^2 \ ,$$
where the last equality follows from the fact that $V$ is orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that
$$||Av||\geq\sigma_{min}$$
for every vector $v$ with $||v||=1$. Let $(e_1,...,e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis in which $A$ is diagonal, $\lambda_1=\sigma_{min},...,\lambda_n$ the associated eigenvalues in increasing order, and write $v=\sum_{i=1}^nv_ie_i$. Then
$$Av=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iv_ie_i$$
so that (by orthonormality of the basis):
$$||Av||^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2||v_i||^2$$
Since $\lambda_1\leq...\leq\lambda_n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n||v_i||^2=1$, the minimum of this function is assumed if $v_1=1$ and $v_2=...=v_n=0$ so that
$$||Av||^2\geq\lambda_1^2=\sigma_{min}^2$$

Comment: Aren't you in fact assuming $U=V^*$ in the SVD decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^*$?

Comment: Was this meant for the other answer?

Comment: No, I meant it. Sorry, I just saw at the OP's end that we take $A$ definite positive, I thought $A$ was general (and we needed to consider $AA^*$ instead)